# If i fetch data within a layout does the fetched data get cached?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm fetching data in the layout of my Next application to grab user information and pass that information down to child components. I'm wondering if by fetching in the layout the fetch is being cached preventing multiple fetches that provide the same data? I've read through the Next docs that fetches are cached by default unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Next.js 14 App Router does cache `fetch` in RSC by default. You can simply fetch the same data in different components, and Next.js takes care of good cache defaults.

There are more cache options and functions and different caches and strategies.

1. [Great Tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app)
2. [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching)
3. [unstable_cache](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_cache)
4. [unstable_noStore](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_noStore)
5. [Deep Dive: Caching and Revalidating (advanced)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/54075)

Comment: I'm trying to test this out in dev and it doesn't seem to be caching as its making request out to the api.. I can see this in the api logs. Is it not possible to see the caching in dev ?

Comment: `next build; next start` produces and serves a production build. But `fetch` should work in dev mode equally. So you observe the endpoint? Does it at least memorize in the component tree (per request)? Possibly, I'm not quite sure (never tested), you have to deploy to Vercel to get a cache persisting between requests. https://vercel.com/docs/infrastructure/data-cache

Comment: What you describe in your question should work. E.g. A page includes two RSC. Both need the same data. `fetch(`https://my-api/77)`. This should request your API only once. At least I read this out of the docs.